# How to use phpQuery and SQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpquery

I need to check whether the data from $var in sql table, and set StopTime parameter. 
But get error: Invalid argument supplied for foreach(). What is the problem?

```
$url='http://somesite/';  
$pars = file_get_contents($url);
$document = phpQuery::newDocument($pars);
$var=$document->find('td:nth-child(10n)')->text();
foreach ($var as $value){
$query = "UPDATE (
            SELECT `Id`id, `UserName` 
                FROM `table`
                WHERE `UserName` IN ('".$value."') 
                )unic_table
                JOIN `table` as r ON r.`Id` = unic_table.id
                SET r.`StopTime` = now( ) ";
$result = mysql_query($query);
}
```

Comment: Means that $var most likely is not an array.. Var_dump($var) to see what's inside..

Comment: Not related but is this a typo `SELECT \`Id\`id`?

Comment: so how to create array from $var?

Comment: $var should be an array according to the phpQuery specs, however it is useful to check whether it is null or empty as @Dieter suggests... You should have an if (!empty($var)) { } wrapped round the foreach to protect against this type of error, or even use is_array

Comment: is it an array then - don't keep us in suspense! :-)

Comment: @vogomatix: you take the words out of my mouth :)

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to iterate:

```
$document->find('td:nth-child(10n)')->text()
```

Which is a string. You want:

```
$document->find('td:nth-child(10n)')
```

which is a DomNodeList